# Block Confirmation too slow

Tags: metamask

Block Confirmation get 200000 till now it's been ten days my transection is stuck and too slow block Confirmation and it's in internal transection

Comment: Could you rewrite the question to be  easier to understand, add the hash of the transaction and the actual question?

Comment: Can you provide a transaction hash? If the gas price provided is too low it might take too long for a transaction to be mined, or it could be dropped if the network gas price keeps high enough.